# Convert this nested if to reduce dimensions as I am expecting to add more strings in the future

Tags: php

This is my code. I cant post actual code but you can see only at 3 strings im ending up with crazy dimension. How can i write this in a way that is conducive to including more than say 10 values?

```
$x = 'a';
$y = 'b';
$z = 'c';

if ($x){
  if($y){
     if($z){
        return $x.$y.$z;
     }
     return $x.$y;
  } 
  return $x;
}

if($y){
  if($z){
    return $y.$z;
  }
  return $y;
}

if($z){
  return $z;
}

return "";
```

Comment: Use a data structure that's actually representative of what the data actually _is_, the most basic being an array, then you can use array functions and/or loops. For multi-level, arbitrarily _deep_ data structures there's recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your nested ifs, you can concatenate strings based on their truthy value like this:

```php
$x = 'a';
$y = 'b';
$z = 'c';

$result = '';

if ($x) $result .= $x;
if ($y) $result .= $y;
if ($z) $result .= $z;

return $result;
```

For future strings, just add:

```php
if ($newVariable) $result .= $newVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do these strings have to be stored in separate variables? if you can store them in an array you can use `implode()` to concatenate them.

E.g.

```
$strs = [];
$strs[] = 'a';
$strs[] = 'b';
$strs[] = 'c';

return implode('',$strs); // abc
```

Comment: Provided this is an option, this looks more sophisticated and scalable; with loops. =)